# Using a hashtable to replace values characters within an array

Tags: java, hashtable

So i have a hashtable with a structure like this `"m" : "q"` with the first character being the thing we're searching for then to replace it with the second character. Now i have an array with each element being a string that needs to be printed with the swap being made. So the question is how would i do this? with the array not being able to change with the replacements kept in mind.

Comment: Can you pasted your code to see what exactly you're doing?

Comment: @GeorgeSmith Do you think that you can share the relevant code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public void swapCharactersAndPrint(String[] data, Map<Character, Character> replacements) {
        for (String string : data) {
            for (char c : string.toCharArray()) {
                if (replacements.containsKey(c)) System.out.print(replacements.get(c));
                else System.out.print(c);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
```